# how to make a videoview NOT started automatically after prepared

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have created a videoview with a standard `media controller` on it. I was **able** to play the video by calling `start()` method in `setOnPreparedListener`, so the video will play automatically when it finished preparing it self.

However, what i want to do is to make the video stand-by (**NOT** playing automatically), so the user need to tap/click/touch the videoview to start the video.

I've done some googling, and i also tried to `setOnTouchListener` on my videoview and calling the `start()` method there. But the result is unexpected (and confusing as well), a **pop up dialog** appears and said **"The video cant be played"**.

This is the complete code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        player = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.player);

        Bundle video = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(video != null)
        {
            id = video.getString("id");
            title = video.getString("title");
            rtsp = video.getString("rtsp");
        }

        txtTitle.setText(title);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(player);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(rtsp);
            player.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            player.setVideoURI(uri); 
            player.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.requestFocus();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pDialog.dismiss();
                player.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                //the video will be played if i call the start() method here
            }
        });

        player.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //"The video cant be played" pop up dialog appeared, video wont start
                player.start();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I got confuse because it **can be played** when i put the `start()` method in `setOnPreparedListener` but it **couldn't** when i put it in `setOnTouchListener`.

I don't know if this is related to the problem or not, but **im buffering a youtube video** (RTSP link) on my videoview.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please help, anyone... :D

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but my reputation is not high enough. I do not see you calling `prepare()` method so probably you are trying to invoke `start()` when player is in `initialized` state. You might try to set the `onTouchListener` of `player` object in the `onPrepared()` callback.